# How can I make IntelliJ use manifest's Automatic-Module-Name?

Tags: intellij-idea, java-9

I have a jar whose manifest includes the `Automatic-Module-Name` entry (so Java 9 will not auto-name it using the jar file name, but the name given by this manifest entry).

I then "require" this module in the module file and it works fine when compiling and running the application... but IntelliJ does not seem to recognize it, as it marks both the "requires" directive in the module file and the "import" in the Java class using it as errors!

Is there a known work-around, or do I have to configure something to make IntelliJ "know" that this particular jar represents a module with a certain name?

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of what error does intelliJ reads?

Comment: It just shows the same error as if you typed the name of a module that didn't exist at all.

Comment: It should be working.. Try with version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion . If problem remain, please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the sample project so that developers could reproduce it.

Comment: I didn't work with 2017.3.4, but with the 2018.1.EAP version it works! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be supported in IntelliJ IDEA (Community Edition) version 2017.3.4, which is the latest as of writing... but the EAP version is available for download already, and it supports the `Automatic-Module-Name` manifest entry... so to get this working, until version 2018.1 is released, use the [EAP version](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion) (I installed it using [Jetbrains Toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/), which I highly recommend to manage all Jetbrains tools in one place).

Comment: Where do you specify the automatic module name so that IntelliJ recognizes it? I add it via Gradle's `jar` task, but that doesn't seem to be seen by IntelliJ.